# Why would the swift language designers choose to seperare numbers by underscores instead of a comma

Tags: swift

Numeric literals can contain extra formatting to make them easier to read. Both integers and floats can be padded with extra zeroes and can contain underscores to help with readability. Neither type of formatting affects the underlying value of the literal:

```
let paddedDouble = 000123.456
let oneMillion = 1_000_000
let justOverOneMillion = 1_000_000.000_000_1
```

Answer (score 8):

Well for one thing not all locales separate numbers with commas. Moreover, using comma separators could become confusing syntactically; consider the following function call:

```
foo(123,456)
```

Is it one literal `123,456`, or two distinct arguments `123` and `456`?

Answer (score 3):

Reason #1: Commas would be ambiguous – it would be impossible to distinguish the following cases:

```
var prices: [Double] = [1,234.00, 99.99]

# evaluates to

var prices: [Double] = [1.00, 234.00, 99.99]
```

However underscores are not ambiguous in this case:

```
var prices: [Double] = [1_234.00, 99.99]
```

Reason #2: The underscore is generally used to indicate a discarded value which makes sense in this context (it is essentially a discarded digit).

Reason #3: Swift is inspired by Ruby, which does the same thing.

Comment: Ruby? Another reason why I don't use it...

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Swift language designer (and I'm not sure anyone who is posts on SO in any official capacity, so this might not be the best place for directing questions at them), but I have a couple of guesses:

- the comma is an operator in Swift (works about the same as in C)
- not everybody uses comma as the thousands separator
- you can use underscore to break up any numeric literal in any way that helps it be readable to you, not just as a thousands separator